# Parsing all the text inside a tag using lxml in python

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

I am trying to parse an HTML file which kind of is as shown below

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="c1">
      <span class="s1">hi</span>
      " hello "
      <span class="s2">world!</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="c2">
      <span class="s3">abc</span>
      " def ghijkl "
      <span class="s1">mno</span>
      " pqr!"
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

I tried to parse using the following code

```
tree = html.fromstring(code.content)
sol = tree.xpath('//ol//text()')
for x in sol:
    print x
```

I get the result as this

```
hi
 hello 
world!
abc
 def ghijkl
mno
 pqr!
```

What can I do to get all the text in each `<li>` tag in one line. i.e. I want the output to be

```
hi hello world!
abc def ghijkl mno pqr!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat a.py
from lxml import etree

xml = """<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="c1">
      <span class="s1">hi</span>
      " hello "
      <span class="s2">world!</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="c2">
      <span class="s3">abc</span>
      " def ghijkl "
      <span class="s1">mno</span>
      " pqr!"
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>"""

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
sol = tree.xpath('//ol//li')
for a in sol:
   print " ".join([t.strip() for t in a.itertext()]).strip()

$ python a.py
hi " hello " world!
abc " def ghijkl " mno " pqr!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get each li and use [normalize-space](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256063(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
from lxml import html
h = """<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="c1">
      <span class="s1">hi</span>
      " hello "
      <span class="s2">world!</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="c2">
      <span class="s3">abc</span>
      " def ghijkl "
      <span class="s1">mno</span>
      " pqr!"
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>"""


tree = html.fromstring(h)

for li in tree.xpath("//ol/li"):
    print(li.xpath("normalize-space(.)"))
```

Which gives you:

```
hi " hello " world!
abc " def ghijkl " mno " pqr!"
```